# deploying wabapps (e.g. moodle) on heroku

Tags: wordpress, drupal, heroku, moodle

What is the proper way to deploy webapps on Heroku? I'm installing Moodle, but the same procedure should apply to e.g. Drupal or Wordpress. What I hace done is to unzip Moodle locally, then uploaded it using git to Heroku. When I then visit my site I get the option to install it and select the database, which works fine. The problem is that the install procedure saves information in the filesystem on the server, which gets overwritten next time I deploy my app. So what is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Hello Mikael, I'm trying to set up moodle on heroku but the $CFG->dataroot setting has few problems here. I would like to know how you solved this? Keep saying Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

Comment: @TheFinestArtist Would like to help, but I haven't seen that error, so no idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pre-configure your app with all of the database settings before you deploy to Heroku. So either do a fake "install" on your local environment, or manually edit your php config files.

As you've discovered, Heroku's filesystem is **not** persistent: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What I did in the end was to manually set up the config files before uploading. Actually, as an aid I did an install on Heroku, then I looked at the generated config file that was created by the install procedure to see that I got everything properly set up.

Comment: @MikaelLindqvist Hello Mikael, I'm trying to set up moodle on heroku but the $CFG->dataroot setting has few problems here. I would like to know how you solved this? Keep saying Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.